# Why is the $_FILES array empty, yet $_POST displays?

Tags: php, arrays, file, upload, superglobals

```
<?php
var_dump($_POST);
var_dump($_FILES);
?>
<!doctype html>
<form id="register_form" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="4194304" />
 <input type="file" name="file_upload" accept="image/*" /><br>
 <input type="submit" value="Upload" id="submit_button">
</form>
```

When uploading a file, for example, tipsfedora.png, I get the file in the $_POST array, yet no files in the $_FILES array. Any help would be appreciated. Full code is posted. I would like to use the files with bulletProof image upload, yet the problem is that $_FILES is an empty array.

Comment: Why are you echoing a var_dump? A var_dump returns void.

Comment: @KodleeYin it's a bad habit of mine. Sorry.

Answer (score 3):

`$_FILES` contains content of uploaded files. But you actually didn't upload any files because the form doesn't have `enctype` attribute. It is required to enable file uploading.

But even you didn't upload any file, `$_POST` contains the file name.

Solution? Just add to `enctype="multipart/form-data"` to the `<form>`.

The [MDN document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-enctype) about `enctype` may help you.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to add

```
enctype="multipart/form-data"
```

to the `<form>` tag